# PHP check array

Tags: php

There is a variable `$list`, which has some array.

```
printr_r($list);
```

Gives something like:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [ID] => 1
        [name] => Martha Dandridge
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [ID] => 35
        [name] => Abigail Smith
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [ID] => 153
        [name] => Julia Gardiner
    )
    [3] => stdClass Object (
        [ID] => 271
        [name] => Hillary Rodham
    )
    [4] => stdClass Object (
        [ID] => 124
        [name] => Nancy Davis
    )
)
```

We should check, if any entry of this array has wanted value in `[name]`.

Like:

```
if($list has "Nancy Davis" or "Hillary Rodham" in [name] of some entry?) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

We have both "Nancy Davis" and "Hillary Rodham" in our array, so it should give `true`.

If we ask like this:

```
  if($list has "George Bush" or "Lou Henry" or "Helen Herron" in [name] of some entry?) { ... }
```

It should give `false`, because there aren't such values in any `name`.

There can be any number of entries in array (I mean `[0], [1] ... [any]`), it should check `[name]` of each entry.

Comment: What did YOU try so far?

Comment: Is this homework? Re: *Please give working code for this.* : this is not how SO works (actually it is considered to be rude to ask for code). Please show what you have got so far.

Comment: You may have the wrong impression of how this site works. We can *assist* you, but we need some help on your end. You can't expect us to give you the code without you getting your hands a bit dirty. It would help to post what you have tried, if anything.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that the impression is not *that* wrong, after all. There are just *some* of us who are not so desperate for virtual points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$match = false;
foreach($list as $value){
  if($value->name == "George Bush" || $value->name =="Lou Henry" || $value->name == "Helen Herron") {
    $match = true;
    break;
  }
}

if($match) {
  // do some if true
} else {
  // do dome if false
}
```

Comment: `or` is valid in Python but not in PHP. And even if you replace `or` with `||` it won't work. The `if` statement is just wrong.

Comment: I've updated the code. @Felix Kling you're correct, 12 hours for the work speak for themselves.

Comment: if($value->name == "George Bush" or "Lou Henry" or "Helen Herron") - this is true logically, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try use the [php in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

```
if (in_array('Martha Dandridge', $list) || in_array('Abigail Smith', $list)) {
    # do something based on the fact that the elements are in the array $list
} else {
    # do something else based on the fact the the elements do no exist in the array $list
}
```

Comment: I just edited my code snippet, that should help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go with
`if ($arr['Janice'] !== null || $arr['Bill'] !== null) {
...
}`